# An error for excel download in firefox for JMeter script recording

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, socketexception

I am recording one script using JMeter. On webpage there are two options two download data. One is excel and one is csv. The csv format data is downloading successfully but when clicking on excel icon to download data it is giving an error as shown in below image.

[image]

I tried one solution as mentioned on different forum but it is not working.
Added below lines in user.properties file.

```
httpclient4.retrycount=1
hc.parameters.file=hc.parameters
httpclient4.idletimeout=1
```

and added below line in hc.parameters

```
http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true
```

It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is for different problem, you shouldn't be blindly copying and pasting configuration amendments without understanding what it's all about.

At the moment I can suggest only the following hints:

1. Double check your [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) and browser configuration, pay special attention to the **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation, ensure that JMeter's certificate is imported in the browser, it's not expired, etc.
2. [Increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
   <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
   ```

this way you should see way more information in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
3. If the above steps won't help or give a clue you can try out an alternative recording solution like [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri...Its not working...need to check some other solutions.

Comment: What is "not working"? Checking the certificate or increasing logging level?

Comment: Both above steps are not resolving my issue. and I want to test it on firefox hence Chrome extension (Blazemeter) is not required.